# Flex: Changing states sometimes fail to change display

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a flex3 web application that displays some data from the server on the same page by using the **states** class.

The MXML code part is this:

```
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="Chart">
        <mx:AddChild position="lastChild">
            <ns2:ChartPanel right="10" top="182" left="10" bottom="10"></ns2:ChartPanel>
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
    <mx:State name="List">
        <mx:AddChild position="lastChild">
            <ns2:TabularPanel right="10" top="182" left="10" bottom="10"></ns2:TabularPanel>
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
    <mx:State name="ChatHistory">
        <mx:AddChild position="lastChild">
            <ns2:ChatHistoryPanel right="10" top="182" left="10" bottom="10"></ns2:ChatHistoryPanel>
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
</mx:states>
```

**ChartPanel** is using an AreaChart to display the data, while **TabularPanel** and **ChatHistoryPanel** use a DataGrid.

I switch between states by setting currentState:

```
protected function onCriteriaChange(event:Event):void
{
    if (criteria.selectedLabel == "Chat History")
    {
    refreshChatHistory();
        currentState = "ChatHistory";
    }
    else
    {
    UsersModel.unique = criteria.selectedIndex;
    if (btnChart.selected)
    {
                    UsersDataController.getNumParticipants();
            currentState = "Chart";
        }
        if (btnList.selected)
        {
            UsersDataController.getListOfParticipants();
            currentState == "List";
        }
    }
}
```

The initial state is 'Chart'.

Here's the problem:

Switching between states works fine except when I switch from 'ChatHistory' to 'List'. The display does not change but remains on the ChatHistoryPanel content.

I am totally clueless to what the problem may be. I wasn't able to find any solution.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, or even a workaround to what I'm trying to do.

I'm using: Flash Builder 4.5, Flex3, Windows 7, Chrome

Many thanks!

Ofer

Comment: Show us the code that does the actual switching. And is there any reason why your are not using a ViewStack for this?

Comment: I inherited this code and added my own state, I'll look into ViewStack.
The code snippet for changing the currentState was added above in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your state switching code, you have the following:

```
    if (btnList.selected)
    {
        UsersDataController.getListOfParticipants();
        currentState == "List"; //This checks equality instead of updating the property
    }
```

And you should change this into:

```
    if (btnList.selected)
    {
        UsersDataController.getListOfParticipants();
        currentState = "List"; //This effectively updates your currentState property
    }
```

It was thus a mere typo :P

Cheers

Comment: OMG, such a lame error :) Isn't there a warning or compiler error in Flash Builder 4.5 for such cases??

Comment: @oferbar, no warning or error (since it's not an error and perfectly good code).  However, as Dennis mentions, you should probably use ViewStack instead of states for this.  It's simpler to use and I remember states being a pain in the ass back in Flex 3.  Much improved in Flex 4 :)